# Kernel panic - json_object_array_length

Tags: boot, kernel

So, I get kernel panic on boot now. It says

> /sbin/init: symbol lookup error: /sbin/init: undefined symbol: json_object_array_length
>   Attempted to kill init blah blah

I blame the json-c (https://github.com/json-c/json-c) library I installed just before the last reboot cycle.

Recovery mode obviously doesn't work. FS is RW mountable and works. Any ideas how to fix this without reinstalling the system? Thanks!

Comment: Have the same issue :( But `make uninstall` crashed system. How did you solved the problem?

Comment: Problem solved with `make uninstall` (@Moein 's answer used to boot). System crash (lower comment) was related with file system.

Answer (score 1):

try to load `/bin/sh` instead of `/sbin/init` at boot and remove `json-c` library.

to do it

1. at GRUB press **ESCAPE** then press **e** to edit boot option
2. On the following screen, highlight the **kernel** line and press **e**
3. On the next screen, which should have a line that says `grub edit>` append `init=/bin/sh` and press ENTER
4. Finally, press **b** to boot the system.

bash should be load and now you can remove mentioned library.

Comment: I got the same kernel panic, (Ubuntu 13.04) and I haven't installed this package from source before. From a Live CD chroot (booting into /bin/sh didn't work for me), installing json-c from source then doing a make uninstall fixed it for me. See also: https://github.com/json-c/json-c/issues/103